# Is there a method to get Mongodb time in a nodejs program?

Tags: mongodb

I want to get Mongodb machine time in my nodejs program(not my local time), how can I write the sql?

Comment: You mean something like [`db.adminCommand({ hostInfo: 1})`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/command/hostInfo/#syntax)?

Answer (score 0):

There is no "SQL" in mongodb, anyway you have to use

```
db.hostInfo()
```

More about it, [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/command/hostInfo/#mongodb-data-hostInfo). So now you can access to

```
hostInfo.system.currentTime
```

to get the timestamp of the current system time.